# lazy loading images with jQuery Isotope grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-isotope

After testing Salvattore, vGrid, and Masonry, etc etc and all other grids that claim to give you masonry style grids but fail to deliver, I finally settled for Isotope, unfortunately as I split my data loading into small chucks so the grid starts rendering faster, there is an issue each time new data arrives when it shows images coming in behind the first column on the left top...it looks like the images are coming in through the top and you can see how the go down to the bottom of the grid. Is there a way to fix this? Can I tell Isotopes to add the new elements to the grid directly to the bottom instead of having it repaint the whole grid each time?

Ideally I will like the new data to go straight to the bottom so the user doesn't even know that more data came in unless you are staring at the scroll bar.

Has anyone done that? Am using Angular 1.2 and tried all the directives there are out there for angular but with large datasets you pretty much has to do your own work.

Edited:
You can see it live in this staging server: 
http://beta.catalogs.com/search/index.htm

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html

You might need to reinitialize isotope after you've added the new data to the DOM.

Comment: Need to see some code....